# Routing in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, dns

How can I create a route like this in the url

```
Localhost:4578//Home/Index/1/2/3/4/5/6
```

I tried making a custom url using routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC.

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot use double slash after your port number,

Imagine, you have a CategoryController

Its class name will be like this

```
[Route("admin/category")]
public class CategoryController : Controller
```

and after that you will have a method returning ActionResult or something else in this controller

```
[Route("upper-categories/add")]
public async ActionResult UpperCategoryAdd()
```

You access this method by using /admin/category/upper-categories/add

and if you want to use an id or something like that

you should use {id} on it

```
[Route("upper-categories/edit/{id}")]
```